# Link to other page (à la MVC Html.ActionLink)

Tags: asp.net, razor, nancy

I'm using ASP.NET-hosted Nancy with the Razor view engine. On my dev machine, the application runs directly in the root virtual directory, but on our CI, we deploy the application to a subfolder:

Example URL of the Welcome page:

On my dev machine: `http://localhost/Welcome`

On the CI machine: `http://localhost/Application42/Welcome`

Showing the welcome page itself is not a problem, but I can't get correct links to other pages. Among other options, I tried

```
<a href="@Url.Content("Page2")">Go to page 2</a>
```

but without success. In MVC, I would use the `@Html.ActionLink()` helper, but that one seems not to be available in Nancy.

What is the correct way to emit links to other pages in Nancy using Razor? Retrieving the base URL of the Application (like `http://localhost/Application42` on the CI machine) would help, but I did't find information about that.

I also have a similar problem in a Response.AsRedirect() call.

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/Page2")">Go to page 2</a>
```

Comment: You don't even need the @Url.Content, just <a href="~/Page2">Go to page 2</a> will do.